# Ошибка opencv python. Распознавание лиц

Tags: python, opencv

У меня есть код который распознаёт лица.
код:

```
import cv2

face_cascade_db = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    #img = cv2.imread("IMG_20191012_145410_3.jpg")
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade_db.detectMultiScale(img_gray, 1.1, 19)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('rez', img)
    #cv2.waitKey()
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

и выдаёт ошибку:

```
[ERROR:0@0.060] global persistence.cpp:512 cv::FileStorage::Impl::open Can't open file: 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Alex\thonny-4.1.1-windows-portable\lib\site-packages\cv2\data\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' in read mode
```

Comment: У вас даже слова выдают ошибки, а вы хотите лица распознавать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо просто поменять название своей модели.

Comment: ⚠ для проверяющих. Это самоответ на не очень качественный вопрос. Тем не менее сам ответ отражает суть того, что происходило в вопросе. ИМХО, нет смысла удалять.